# Capture a download link redirected by a page (WGET)

Tags: windows, url, redirect, download, wget

Here is my problem.

I am currently working on a script for me that automates the download of some software that I use to "clean" my computer.

I have been able to make downloads with download URLs like this one: "https://www.driverscloud.com/plugins/DriversCloud_Win.exe" but not with URLs that redirect to a download URL after a short time of waiting like this one: "https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard".

I can see that the problem is that I don't give a direct download address to Wget but I would like to be able to do it with the address "https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard" because Piriform (the developer of Ccleaner) updates the software quite regularly and the download address changes according to the version number (example: https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup547.exe -> https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup548.exe).

So how can I ask Wget to take the download link contained in the page and not download the page itself (because I get a file called "standard" like at the end of the URL "https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard" ?

I would be delighted if you have a solution for me with Wget or other tools like Curl :) .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PHP for that. `wget` alone is powerful enough to do this simple job :)

Here's the command you need (I'll give a breakdown below):

```
$ wget -r -l 1 --span-hosts --accept-regex='.*download.ccleaner.com/.*.exe' -erobots=off -nH https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard
```

Now, for a breakdown of what this does:

- `-r`: Enables recursion since we want to follow a link on the provided page
- `-l 1`: We want to recurse only one level deep since the required URL is on the same page
- `--span-hosts`: The required file is on a different host than the original URL we provide. So we ask wget to go across hosts when using recursion
- `--accept-regex=...`: This specifies a regular expression of the links that will be accessed through recursion. Since we only want one file and know the pattern, we make pretty specific regex.
- `-erobots=off`: The `download.ccleaner.com` host has a `robots.txt` that forbids all user-agents. But we're not crawling the domain, so disable honoring the robots file
- `-nH`: Don't create host specific directories. This means the exe will be downloaded directly into your current folder now.

If you want a little more automation, you can also append a `&& rm -r fr-fr/` to the above command to remove the base page that you downloaded in order to get the right link.

Enjoy!

EDIT: Since OP is on Windows, here is an updated command specifically for running on Windows. It doesn't single-quote the regex string since that causes the Windows shell to pass the regex as a string with single quotes.

```
$ wget -r -l 1 --span-hosts --accept-regex=.*download.ccleaner.com/.*.exe -erobots=off -nH https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but i tried it and it stills download a file named "standard' without extension. It looks like i can't follow the redirection on this site.

Comment: That should not happen. Can you add a `-d` to that command and then share the entire output? Put it up on maybe pastebin? I can run the command perfectly fine from my end so I'd like to investigate why it won't work on yours

Comment: Sorry for the late, here is the pastebin of the command with the -d added https://pastebin.com/Ux7rrc49

Comment: I see. It seems like your regex backend is the issue. Out of curiosity, could you please post the result of `wget --version` as well? And one solution to your problem is to use `'.*download.ccleaner.com\/.*.exe'` as the regex string. (Notice that the slash has been escaped)

Comment: I tried the slash escaped solution, same problem. I have a folder and sub-folder in it -> fr-fr/ccleaner/download with a file named standard in it.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look again. Seems like the issue is specific to the Windows port. Most likely an issue due to the lack of libpcre for regex.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is on the regex side ? It seems to be with the redirection because if i delete the regex parameter it's downloading all except the exe file. Or maybe I havn't understood a thing ?

Comment: Your original pastebin output has the following line: `https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup549.exe is excluded/not-included through regex.` Which leads me to believe that it is happening due to the regex parsing.

Comment: Aah, I don't use windows, so it took some time to figure it out. The Windows shell passes strings slightly differently than unix shells. I've updated the original answer with the correct version (Ran it on a Windows VM this time, it works)

Comment: Thx for all, it works, I have continued my script and i'm confronted with an other problem with the same downloads (the ccleaner and the defraggler ones). The problem is that the "standard" file is downloaded in addition to the exe file

Answer (score 0):

wget spider mode *might* be able to do it, but this isn't a job for either curl nor wget, you need to fetch the download page, and then extract the download url to the newest version from that html, some pages also provide a cookie in the download page, and requires you to submit this cookie to download the actual file, this is a job for a language that understands HTTP and HTML. [PHP](https://windows.php.net/) is one such language, taking ccleaner's download page as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://www.ccleaner.com/fr-fr/ccleaner/download/standard");
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '',
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$download_element = $xp->query('//a[contains(text(),"start the download")]')->item(0);
$download_url = $download_element->getAttribute("href");
$download_name = basename($download_url); // fetching it from the headers of the download would be more reliable but cba
echo "download name: \"{$download_name}\" - url: {$download_url}\n";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $download_url);
$installer_binary = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents($download_name, $installer_binary);
```

this script fetches the download page, then extracts the "href" (url) attribute of the `<a href="download_url">start the download</a>` element containing the text `start the download`, then downloads whatever that url points to. this is beyond the scope of wget/curl, use a scripting language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great job, i hadn't thought about the PHP solution. My new question will be : can I launch the PHP script from my batch script ? (Because I forgot to say that I am on Windows).

Comment: @Spekuloos sure, if php is available on the computer. windows PHP buils are available here https://windows.php.net/download/ - you can call from batch scripts like `C:\php\php.exe script.php`, or if php.exe's folder is added to windows's %path% variable, you can just run it like `php script.php` (i usually add php to the path variable on my own systems)

Comment: Ok, In my case I just put the php folder in my project folder and i use it with a relative path in my batch script. There is still one problem left. When I launch the script it says that curl_init isn't a defined function. Do i have to download a library or something ? Edit: I don't have any php.ini in my php folder is that normal ?

Comment: @Spekuloos no. next to php.exe is a file called `php.ini-development`, rename it to `php.ini`, then open `php.ini` in notepad, there you will find a line saying `;extension=curl`, remove the semicolon from that line (so it becomes `extension=curl`), and save it. then curl_init should work

Comment: @Spekuloos just occurred to me: because you're going to use httpS SSL/TLS-protected websites, you may also need to do the same with the line that says  `;extension=openssl`  (libcurl may use openssl to decrypt httpS)

Comment: Ok, thx for your help but I wanted to share the finished script with some of my friends so they could use it, but the project folder is getting heavy with the PHP installation coupled with wget. Basically I wanted a small script that would handle everything and I ended up with several libraries. Is there a way that i can use just one "solution" to do all i need.

Comment: In addition to that an error appears even after enabling curl support and I think it has something to do with environment variables, so if my friends need to add PATH variable it won't be a portable installation.

Comment: @Spekuloos maybe you should learn C/C++? most .bat files can be trivially ported with system() command (because each line of .bat is pretty much a system() command), libcurl can be statically compiled in, and your entire distribution can be a single .exe file

Comment: Do you think that i can do my project on a Website using PHP/HTML/JAVA(maybe)/CSS. Like this i can integrate explanations about the softwares and make presentations on how to use them etc... I ask this because I'm much more comfortable with the web programming than with software programming.

Comment: @Spekuloos: Yes, you can do the whole thing here without PHP or libcurl. Just the wget command will be enough. Take a look at my answer for the full command