# Wget to download software with a changing URL

Tags: powershell, wget

Setting up a PowerShell script to auto-download applications with varying URLs.

I had a batch file script to download certain application to ensure my USB Toolkit was always updated. However I want to switch to powershell because I found it had the WGET command to download direct from a URL. What I was hoping, was to have the URL always get the latest version.

```
wget https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup556.exe -O ccleaner.exe
```

Note that the 556 in the URL is the variable I would like to always select the highest version.

They have two download pages, a direct link, and one that takes 2-5 seconds to download, however when I point `wget` to that page, it just downloads the HTML webpage.

Comment: Is there an option with the wget command to follow redirects?

Comment: I don't get why people are still using this piece of trash, but anyway, this should download the latest version: `wget https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup.exe`. Note that this works b/c the vendor also provides the latest version as a download without the version number in the file name. It may not work for other vendors/applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture a download link redirected by a page (WGET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189651/capture-a-download-link-redirected-by-a-page-wget)